# PostgreSQL - How to identify three roles of users in database?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design

I'm building a database schema that needs three kind of user roles: normal user, admin and super admin. My first approach was to make two tables, one for the normal user and one for both the admin and super admin that inherits from the users table. So the table definitions were like this:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  email TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  password TEXT NOT NULL,
  name TEXT NOT NULL,
  gender CHAR NOT NULL,
  created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

CREATE TABLE admins (
  phone BIGINT NOT NULL,
  doc BIGINT NOT NULL,
  super_admin BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
  id BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES users(id)
);
```

But I'm not sure how to SELECT a user or an admin when needed. So now I'm thinking if it is better to leave just one "users" table and define a new table "roles" where users will be matched, in order to SELECT them with a column "role" that specifies if an user is normal, admin or super admin.

Comment: You can have a new roles table and have a `role` column in your users table with a FK reference. The thing is if you would someday want to have users with multiple roles, it would be slightly more difficult as that would mean a many to many relationship which would normally imply a intermediate table. You might want to try a Flag enum approach, where assign Super Admin = 1, Admin =2, Normal = 4, Supervisor = 8 etc. Now a user can have a role of `Normal | Supervisor` and the where clause to check for supervisor becomes `(user.role & 8) = 8`.

Comment: @Sourav'Abhi'Mitra So if a user starts as normal but then he wants to be both normal and admin, it only changes in the Flag column? For example, he starts being 4 and then he changes to 5 (normal + admin meaning).

Comment: @licuadolala yes that is what is meant although (normal+admin) would be (4+2) = 6. This does mean some additional processing logic though.

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily solved by introducing two new tables:

1. Roles - This will contains all types of roles
2. user_roles- For mapping users with roles.

Sample Data:

```
 Roles
 -------------------
 |ID |role_type   | 
 -------------------
 |1 |Admin        |
 |2 |Normal       |
 |3 |Super Admin  |
 -------------------

 user_roles
 ------------------
 |user_id |role_id|
 ------------------
 |1      |1       |
 |1      |2       |
 |2      |3       |
 ------------------
```

`user_roles` table will have `FK reference`with `users` and `roles` table.

Answer (score 0):

First, you shouldn't be storing telephone numbers as integers. You should be using strings.  There exist valid phone numbers in the world can start with `0`, which integers cannot handle.

This can be complicated.  First, I note that you have two additional data fields for admins and supers.  If you include the data in the `users` table, then anyone with access to `users` would have this information.  Normally, this is fine.  However, I could imagine situations where this is an issue.

Postgres directly supports table inheritance (see [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-inherit.html)), so you don't need an explicit foreign key relationship.  Inheritance is a nice way to handle derived user types.  It gives you alternative tables for `admins` and `supers` that you can reference in the `from` clause (and these would also be available for users).

There are two alternatives.  One is to put the additional columns (`phone` and `doc`) in the `users` table, along with an indicator of the type.  This could be a single field ("normal", "admin", "super") or three flags ("IsNormal", "IsAdmin", and "IsSuper").  An alternative is to have a separate `UserRoles` junction table.

Each of these methods has its merits.  Because you have started down the path of multiple tables and you have enhanced data for admins and supers, I would probably recommend inheritance for this specific case.  Note that the syntax might be:

```
CREATE TABLE admins (
  phone BIGINT NOT NULL,
  doc BIGINT NOT NULL
) inherits (users);

CREATE TABLE supers (
  phone BIGINT NOT NULL,
  doc BIGINT NOT NULL
) inherits (users);
```

Comment: In the first alternative what if all columns are mandatory? For example, all roles are defined with the single field and if I want to add a normal user, I should left the phone and doc columns with an empty string?

Comment: @licuadolala . . . You would make them `NULL` rather than an empty string, in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks, I have a last question. Is it better to create a new user for each role or to update the column in the existing user?

Comment: @licuadolala . . . Probably to update the existing user, but there may be other factors in what you are trying to do that might suggest creating a new user.

Answer (score 0):

You can use exists() in a scalar subquery, which yields a boolean expression:

```
INSERT INTO users(email,name,password,gender) VALUES
        ( 'john@world', 'John' , 'John', 'S' ),
        ( 'mary@world', 'mary' , 'mary', 'S' ),
        ( 'Jeff@world', 'Jeff' , 'Jeff', 'J' ) ;

INSERT INTO admins(phone, doc, super_admin, id) VALUES
        ( '007' , 0, False, 2),
        ( '008' , 0, True, 3) ;

SELECT email,name,gender
        , (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM admins a WHERE a.id = u.id)) AS is_admin
        , (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM admins a WHERE a.id = u.id AND a.super_admin)) AS is_super_admin
FROM users u
        ;
```

---

Result:

```
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 3
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 2
   email    | name | gender | is_admin | is_super_admin 
------------+------+--------+----------+----------------
 john@world | John | S      | f        | f
 mary@world | mary | S      | t        | f
 Jeff@world | Jeff | J      | t        | t
```

Do note: the original data model may not be perfect, but the query at least solves the problem at hand. (you could hide it -for instance* in one or two views)